# Factorization of Grammian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive definite matrix in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$. I wonder what could be a necessary and sufficient condition so that there exist a positive definite matrix $P$ satisfying $$A = B * P,$$ where $B*P$ denote the Hadamard (schur) product of two matrices.

I know the question is not that much concrete, But any reference regarding this will be also very helpful.

Comment: A related question: If B is positive definite with each entry being non-zero, is $B^{(-1)}$ (each entry of $B$ inverted) also positive definite? If yes, it is sufficient that all entries of $B$ are non-zero. EDIT: Ok, this is not the case. The question is more involved than I thought...